# How to change DataGridViewComboBoxColumn back to DataGridViewColumn?

Tags: c#

I setup my `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` like this:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn partStatusCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

partStatusCol.DataSource = PostgreSQLConnection.AddDataSet(query.ListPartStatusValue());
partStatusCol.DisplayMember = "Value_Status";
partStatusCol.DataPropertyName = "Part_Status";
partStatusCol.Name = "Part_Status";

if (dataGridView1.Columns.Contains("Part_Status"))
{
    int index = dataGridView1.Columns["Part_Status"].Index;
    dataGridView1.Columns.Remove("Part_Status");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(index, partStatusCol);
}
```

And now i want to reset this stuff and change it back to the ordinary `DataGridViewColumn`.

I tried to reset the `DataSet` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean with "i want to reset this stuff"? I you want it disabled, remove it

Comment: I dont want to remove the column, because i need it, but not with a combobox. I want to change it back to DataGridViewColumn. And without losing the entrys.